# Asymptotics of shifted Catalan numbers

Tags: generating-functions, catalan-numbers

I am trying to understand a lemma from a paper (most of the proof was omitted), and I've got it melted down to the following:
Let $B_n$ denote the $n$-th Catalan Number. In a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $z = \frac{1}{4}$ we have
      \begin{equation}
   \sum_{p \ge p_0} B_p z^p = \frac{C}{\sqrt{\ln (\frac{1}{1-4z})}} + O\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln^3 (\frac{1}{1-4z})}}\bigg)
  \end{equation}
where $p_0 = p_0(z) = \ln \frac{1}{|1-4z|}$ and $C = 2 \sqrt{\ln 4 / \pi}$.
I guess one either has to express it as the difference between the generating function of the Catalan Numbers $B(z) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4z}}{2z} $ and a finite sum of Catalan Numbers, or calculate a series of shifted Catalan Numbers. I've tried both; yet neither one of them yield the desired solution.
      The lemma has been taken from the paper *Analytic Variations on the Common Subexpression Problem* by P. Flajolet et al (Lemma 1). I asked a part of the problem in [question 107773](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107773/generating-function-of-shifted-catalan-numbers/107776#comment252178_107776), where it was suggested that I ask the whole problem, not just a part of it. I would be grateful for any help.